# How to access a gitlab-ce running on a machine behind a router?

Tags: gitlab, devops

I have installed gitlab on my ubuntu server and as far as I can tell its up and running. I'm trying to configure it so that I can access it via my static IP from anywhere. What should I put in the external_url in gitlab.rb ? Should be the local static ip of the server followed by the port number? Basically I want to be able to type http://staticIp:portNum and acces the web interface.

Also if I reconfigure will I loose the root password that was generated for me? I know that the file will be deleted so I copied the pass over just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated by [`gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab` issue 4932](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/4932), you would need to:

- use a static IP of a FQDN (fully qualified name) of your server,  as explained  in "[Configure the external URL for GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configure-the-external-url-for-gitlab)"
- [Configure your NGiNX](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html)

Reconfiguring GitLab should not reset the [initial root password set on installation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#set-initial-root-password-on-installation).